# How do I make an r-script wait for a mouse click?

Tags: r, mouseevent, wait

I have this simple script that I execute from command line (`c:\path\foo> r --ess --slave -q -f myScript.R`):

```
library(ggmap)

x11()
qmap('Hauptbahnhof Zürich', zoom=18, source='osm')
```

I want the script to wait until the user clicks with the mouse into the image. This version just exits.

I tried to use `z <- locator(1)`, yet this gives me a `Error in locator(1) : plot.new has not been called yet Execution halted` error.

I also tried

```
getGraphicsEvent(
    prompt      = "Waiting for input", 
    onMouseDown = NULL,
    onMouseMove = NULL,
    onMouseUp   = NULL, 
    onKeybd     = NULL)
```

yet, this approach just print `NULL` to the console and then exits.

So, how would I go about waiting for the user to click into the image to proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I didn't find an answer to make the script wait until the user clicks with the mouse, at least I can wait for him to press enter on the console:

```
readLines('stdin', n=1)
```